# Cannot display data from database in SelectOneMenu

Tags: hibernate, jsf, selectonemenu

The following code is followed [this tutorial] (http://javaknowledge.info/simple-crud-using-jsf2hibernate-integration-and-mysql/) with some additional problem.

Below is my model:

Customer.java

```
    package com.javaknowledge.entity;
import com.javaknowledge.dao.CustomerDao;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
import java.sql.Blob;
/**
 *
 * @author VENNY
*/
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String VIDPROSPEK;
    private String VNAME;
    private String VADRESS;   
    private String NPHONENUM;
    private String KILOMETER;
    private String TAHUNPRODUKSI;
    private String sd, msg, selectedname;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String VIDPROSPEK, String VNAME, String VADRESS, String NPHONENUM, String TAHUNPRODUKSI, String KILOMETER) {
        this.VIDPROSPEK = VIDPROSPEK;
        this.VNAME = VNAME;
        this.VADRESS = VADRESS;        
        this.NPHONENUM = NPHONENUM;
        this.TAHUNPRODUKSI= TAHUNPRODUKSI;
        this.KILOMETER = KILOMETER;
    }

    public String getSd() {
        return sd;
    }

    public void setSd(String sd) {
        this.sd = sd;
    }

    public String getVIDPROSPEK() {
        return this.VIDPROSPEK;
    }

    public void setVIDPROSPEK(String VIDPROSPEK) {
        this.VIDPROSPEK = VIDPROSPEK;
    }

    public String getVNAME() {
        return this.VNAME;
    }

    public void setVNAME(String VNAME) {
        this.VNAME = VNAME;
    }

    public String getVADRESS() {
        return this.VADRESS;
    }

    public void setVADRESS(String VADRESS) {
        this.VADRESS = VADRESS;
    }

    public String getNPHONENUM() {
        return this.NPHONENUM;
    }

    public void setNPHONENUM(String NPHONENUM) {
        this.NPHONENUM = NPHONENUM;
    }

    public String getKILOMETER() {
        return this.KILOMETER;
    }

    public void setKILOMETER(String KILOMETER) {
        this.KILOMETER = KILOMETER;
    }

   public String getTAHUNPRODUKSI() {
        return this.TAHUNPRODUKSI;
    }

    public void setTAHUNPRODUKSI(String TAHUNPRODUKSI) {
        this.TAHUNPRODUKSI = TAHUNPRODUKSI;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getSelectedname() {
        return selectedname;
    }

    public void setSelectedname(String selectedname) {
        this.selectedname = selectedname;
    }

    public void saveCustomer() {

        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        dao.addCustomer(this);
        this.msg = "Member Info Saved Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }

    public void updateCustomer() {

        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        dao.updateCustomer(this);
        this.msg = "Member Info Update Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }
    public void deleteCustomer() {
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        dao.deleteCustomer(VIDPROSPEK);
        this.msg = "Member Info Delete Successfull!";
        clearAll();
    }

    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> users = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        users = dao.getAllCustomers();
        return users;
    }

    public void fullInfo() {
        CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
        List<Customer> lc = dao.getCustomerById(selectedname);
        System.out.println(lc.get(0).VNAME);
        this.VIDPROSPEK = lc.get(0).VIDPROSPEK;
        this.VNAME = lc.get(0).VNAME;
        this.VADRESS = lc.get(0).VADRESS;       
        this.NPHONENUM = lc.get(0).NPHONENUM;
        this.TAHUNPRODUKSI = lc.get(0).TAHUNPRODUKSI;
        //this.sd = sdf.format(dob);VIMAGE
    }

    private void clearAll() {
        this.VNAME = "";
        this.VADRESS = "";
        this.NPHONENUM="";
        this.KILOMETER="";
    }
}
```

TipeMotor.java

```
package com.javaknowledge.entity; import com.javaknowledge.dao.TipeMotorDAO; import java.text.ParseException; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Date; import java.util.List; import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;/**  *  * @author VENNY  */ @ManagedBean @SessionScoped public class TipeMotor implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String VTYPECODE;
    private String VCLRCODE;
    private String VCLRDESC;   
    private String selectedVCLRDESC;


    public TipeMotor() {
    }

    public TipeMotor(String VTYPECODE, String VCLRCODE, String VCLRDESC) {
        this.VTYPECODE = VTYPECODE;
        this.VCLRCODE = VCLRCODE;
        this.VCLRDESC = VCLRDESC;
    }

    public String getVTYPECODE() {
        return VTYPECODE;
    }

    public void setVTYPECODE(String VTYPECODE) {
        this.VTYPECODE = VTYPECODE;
    }
    public String getVCLRCODE() {
        return VCLRCODE;
    }

    public void setVCLRCODE(String VCLRCODE) {
        this.VCLRCODE = VCLRCODE;
    }

    public String getVCLRDESC() {
        return VCLRDESC;
    }

    public void setVCLRDESC(String VCLRDESC) {
        this.VCLRDESC = VCLRDESC;
    }

    public String getselectedVCLRDESC() {
        return selectedVCLRDESC;
    }

    public void setselectedVCLRDESC(String selectedVCLRDESC) {
        this.selectedVCLRDESC = selectedVCLRDESC;
    }

    public List<TipeMotor> getAllTipeMotors() {
        List<TipeMotor> users = new ArrayList<TipeMotor>();
        TipeMotorDAO dao = new TipeMotorDAO();
        users = dao.getAllTipeMotors();
        return users;
    } }
```

hibernate.reveng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="ahmids"/>
  <table-filter match-name="ahmdsmun_mstprospek"/>
  <table-filter match-name="ahmdsmun_msttypeclr"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Customer.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jul 5, 2013 10:57:32 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.javaknowledge.entity.Customer" table="ahmdsmun_mstprospek" catalog="ahmids">
        <id name="VIDPROSPEK" type="string">
            <column name="VIDPROSPEK" />

        </id>
        <property name="VNAME" type="string">
            <column name="VNAME" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="VADRESS" type="string">
            <column name="VADRESS" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="NPHONENUM" type="string">
            <column name="NPHONENUM" length="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="TAHUNPRODUKSI" type="string">
            <column name="TAHUNPRODUKSI" length="4"/>
        </property>
        <property name="KILOMETER" type="string">
            <column name="KILOMETER" length="100" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and something like that in TipeMotor.hbm.xml

TipeMotorDAO.java

```
package com.javaknowledge.dao;

import com.javaknowledge.entity.TipeMotor;
import com.javaknowledge.util.HibernateUtil;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

/**
 *
 * @author javaknowledge
 */
public class TipeMotorDAO {

    public void addTipeMotor(TipeMotor timot) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(timot);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(int custid) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            TipeMotor cust = (TipeMotor) session.load(TipeMotor.class, new Integer(custid));
            session.delete(cust);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void updateTipeMotor(TipeMotor cust) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(cust);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public List<TipeMotor> getAllTipeMotors() {
        List<TipeMotor> users = new ArrayList<TipeMotor>();
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            users = session.createQuery("select VCLRDESC from ahmdsmun_mstprospek").list();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

something like that in CustomerDAO.java

and class HibernateUtil.jva

and last, here is my index

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
        contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>PKB Mobile</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <pm:page id="customer" title="Hello Primefaces Mobile">
            <pm:header title="PKB MOBILE" >
                <p:commandButton styleClass="ui-btn-right ui-btn-inline" value="Summary" icon="ui-icon-gear" action="#{customer.saveCustomer}" />
                <p:button styleClass="ui-btn-left ui-btn-inline" value="Reset" icon="ui-icon-gear"  />
            </pm:header>
            <pm:content>
                <h:form>
                    <p:tabMenu>
                        <p:menuitem value="Customer" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Service" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Part"/>
                    </p:tabMenu>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="VIDPROSPEK:"/></td>
                            <td><h:inputText value="#{customer.VIDPROSPEK}" id="VIDPROSPEK"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="200">
                                <p:outputLabel for="TAHUNPRODUKSI" value="Tahun Produksi" />
                            </td>                            
                            <td  width="500">
                                <h:selectOneMenu id="TAHUNPRODUKSI" value="#{customer.TAHUNPRODUKSI}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1991" itemValue="1991" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1992" itemValue="1992" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1993" itemValue="1993" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1994" itemValue="1994" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1995" itemValue="1995" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1996" itemValue="1996" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1997" itemValue="1997" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1998" itemValue="1998" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1999" itemValue="1999" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2000" itemValue="2000" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2001" itemValue="2001" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2002" itemValue="2002" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2003" itemValue="2003" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2004" itemValue="2004" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2005" itemValue="2005" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2006" itemValue="2006" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2007" itemValue="2007" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2008" itemValue="2008" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2009" itemValue="2009" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2010" itemValue="2010" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2011" itemValue="2011" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2012" itemValue="2012" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2013" itemValue="2013" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2014" itemValue="2014" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2015" itemValue="2015" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p:outputLabel for="TIPEMOTOR" value="Tipe Motor"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <h:selectOneMenu id="TIPEMOTOR" value="#{tipemotor.selectedVCLRDESC}" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{tipemotor.allTipeMotors}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="200"><p:outputLabel for="kilometer" value="Kilometer" /></td>  
                            <td width="500"><h:inputText value="#{customer.KILOMETER}" id="kilometer"/></td>                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="Nama:"/></td>
                            <td><h:inputText value="#{customer.VNAME}" id="VNAME"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="Alamat:"/></td>
                            <td><h:inputText value="#{customer.VADRESS}" id="VADRESS"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="No. HP:"/></td>
                            <td><h:inputText value="#{customer.NPHONENUM}" id="NPHONENUM"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputLabel value="Foto:"/></td>
                            <td><p:fileUpload value="#{customer.VIMAGE}" mode="simple" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </h:form>
            </pm:content>
        </pm:page>    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

My problem is I cannot display data from table ahmdsmun_msttypeclr in SelectOneMenu with id TIPEMOTOR. How is this can be solved?
Your answer is really appreciated

Comment: @BalusC, I have tried it, but I think something missing. based on the prob, may you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe you tried it. More than 80% of the code posted so far in the question is irrelevant to the problem. Put the current project aside. Create a new one from scratch. Play around with examples shown in the duplicate question until you got the picture. Then compare. In case you still stucks, carefully read [Information to provide when asking JSF questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) before asking a new -and better- question.

Comment: @BalusC yes, i try BUT not in this project. I'm confused in userService because you do not give a whole tutorial but pieces of code. So, I'm stuck while following the code.

Comment: That part is not relevant to JSF. It can do anything you want. It can even return a hardcoded list. It can be called by anything, even a plain Java class with `main()` method. If that method returns null or an empty list, then you know at that point that that problem has completely nothing to do with JSF.

Comment: @BalusC I saw in here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info that init() in SelectOneMenu is filled with the data. But when I want to display data from database, how the init() looks like? I think I can not make it empty

Comment: If you have no idea how to get a `List<T>` from the database in any random Java class, then this problem has nothing to do with JSF.

Comment: @BalusC then, where I miss so the page can not display it?